# Need explanation on subclasses of llvm::Constant

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am currently studying the LLVM IR. I understand that `llvm::Value` is an important class in LLVM, and `llvm::Value` has many derived classes such as `llvm::Function`, `llvm::BasicBlock` and `llvm::Instruction`, etc. One thing that baffles me is the `llvm::Constant` class. It has the following derived classes:

```
llvm::BlockAddress  
llvm::ConstantAggregate  
llvm::ConstantData  
llvm::ConstantExpr  
llvm::DSOLocalEquivalent  
llvm::GlobalValue
llvm::NoCFIValue
```

Here are my questions:

1. What are the meanings of the above classes? Do they have the corresponding source code entities?
2. With regard to the subclasses of `llvm::GlobalValue`, what does `llvm::GlobalAlias` mean? What is the difference between `llvm::Function` and `llvm::GlobalIFunc`?

Could someone give me any ideas, or where can I find the detailed documentation to answer the above questions?

Comment: [ConstantExpr](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantExpr.html) for example. The others are similar. My advice for studying LLVM is to gitclone the source code so that you can look atound it; seeing how parts of LLVM *use* a particular class is often a great help to understaning that class.

Comment: I've read the doxygen page before, but it only gives me class definitions. However, I want to have some high level ideas. For example, when is llvm::GlobalAlias actually needed? Does it correspond to any source code entities?

Comment: The doxygen blah varies in quality. The one for ConstantExpr answers your question in the first sentence, the one for GlobalAlias doesn't answer it at all. I ran `less $(grep -l GlobalAlias **/*.cpp(.))` now to see, and the third or fourth file shows a C++ example that involves GlobalAlias: It's related to `__attribute__`, so fairly obscure.

Comment: Most of them do correspond to source entities. GlobalAlias is a https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#aliases . Some of them are memory-savings tricks, ConstantData represents constant data in memory without corresponding Use objects on each elements (contrast to ConstantArray).

Comment: Specifically regarding `GlobalIFunc` vs `Function`, here's GlobalIFunc: https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#ifuncs and here's Function: https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#functions . The LangRef states that ifuncs "have a resolver" but don't really explain the use case. You can have two implementations of a function like CRC32 and the resolver will pick one of the two based on whether the CPU has a native CRC32 instruction or not. This resolver is not part of LLVM and thus not described in the LangRef (it's part of the OS dynamic loader).

Comment: Thanks for your answers! The LangRef manual is really helpful.  Actually I later found out that GlobalIFunc like GlobalAlias is also related to `__attribute__`.